# How to customize the pipe destination for parsing the data from read stream?

Tags: node.js

I am using `nodejs` to read a very large csv file and I don't want to read all of them into memory. Below is my code:

```
const s = fs
      .createReadStream(url, {
                flags: 'r',
                encoding: 'utf-8',
                fd: null,
                bufferSize: 1
            })
      .pipe( // what should I do here )
```

I don't know what to do in the `pipe` method. According to nodejs document `https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options`, it needs a Writable instance there. I wonder whether I can put customize logic as the Writable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.

Have no 50 reputation yet to comment.

It is possible to write to several built in functions and to file.

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options

That said you should have a look into the API.

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_writable_stream

There you can work on the `chunks`.

```
_write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    if (chunk.toString().indexOf('a') >= 0) {
      callback(new Error('chunk is invalid'));
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }
```